# Input is not required

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

```html
<div ng-repeat="PhoneNumber in PhoneNumbers">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
           @Html.TextBox("PhoneNumber[{{$index}}].Phone", null, new {ng_required="true",@class = "form-control space-bottom",placeholder = "Your Phone Number", ng_modal = "{{PhoneNumber.Phone}}"})
           <div ng-show="subForm.$submitted 
            ||subForm['PhoneNumber['{{$index}}'].Phone'].$touched">
                  <span class="text-danger" ng- 
        show="subForm['PhoneNumber['{{$index}}'].Phone'].$error.required">
                  Tell us your Phone.</span>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">                                
           @Html.DropDownList("PhoneNumber[{{$index}}].Ranking", new 
           SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(RankPhone))),
           "", new { @class = "form-control space-bottom", ng_modal = " 
            {{PhoneNumber.Ranking}}", ng_required="true"})
            <div ng-show="subForm.$submitted || 
             subForm['PhoneNumber['{{$index}}'].Ranking'].$touched">
                    <span class="text-danger" ng- 
            show="subForm['PhoneNumber['{{$index}}'].Ranking'].$error.required">
            Rate your Phone.</span>
            </div>
       </div>
                        
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm working with a phone book and a template (asp .net) is a phone list to be able to create a dynamic form with the angular. the problem is that the phone input has to be required, and ng-required is not working.

Comment: Have you tried using <form> element as wrapper>
Example: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRequired

Comment: already, and did not work.

Comment: If it's always going to be true why not use `required` instead of `ng-required`? Also, isn't it `ng-model`, not `ng-modal`?